# How to create one view from two forms in Zend 2

Tags: php, forms, controller, zend-framework2

I have 2 forms:

- `RegistrationForm`
- `LoginForm`

Each have their own controllers:

- `RegistrationController`
- `LoginController`

I need to render in one view

- `login_register.phtml`

a snippet code for the first form:

```
<?php
    $form = $this->form;
    $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('auth/default', array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'Login')));
    $form->setAttribute('onsubmit', 'onSubmit()');
    $form->prepare();
    echo $this->form()->openTag($form); 
?>
```

a snippet code for the second form:

```
<?php  
    $form = $this->form;
    $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('auth/default', array('controller' => 'registration', 'action' => 'index')));
    $form->prepare();

    echo $this->form()->openTag($form); 
 ?>
```

I am putting them in one form however it is giving errors for not discovering the second form.

> **Zend\Form\Exception\InvalidElementException**
>   No element by the name of [last_name] found in form

**Update :**

I am just declaring the froms and I am not putting any special code to combine them.
I need help because I dont know How to do it??

Comment: @TimFountain Look at the question please.

Comment: @GingerHead Your error is due to a request for a form element that does not exist in the form. You will need to at least post some of the code or we cannot help you.

Comment: @AlexP Updated,look at the Question please

Comment: You controller(s) action code would be more appropriate as the view only renders the form; we need to see how its built (i assume when you say "I am putting them in one form" this is done within a controller?)

Comment: @AlexP  No the controllers are seperate normal controllers. I am doing it in the view, I dont know how to do it????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i did when i wanted to use two forms in one view was to rename them properly. For example,
in your controller where you display the view

```
$form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserLoginForm');
$reform = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserRegisterForm');
$viewModel  = new ViewModel(array(

            'form'      => $form,
            'reform'    => $reform,

            )); 
return $viewModel;
```

And in your phtml file.

```
<?php 
            $reform = $this->reform;
            $reform->prepare();
            $reform->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL, array('controller'=>'Login', 'action' => 'register', 'name'=> 'form', 'class' => 'form')));
            $reform->setAttribute('method', 'post');

            echo $this->form()->openTag($reform);


        ?>
```

the other form.

```
<?php 
                $form = $this->form;
                $form->prepare();
                $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL, array('controller'=>'Login', 'action' => 'register', 'name'=> 'form', 'class' => 'form')));
                $form->setAttribute('method', 'post');

                echo $this->form()->openTag($form);


            ?>
```

This worked for me. all in one view

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways to achieve what you're doing.

## Create a new Controller

This new Controller and it's corresponding action would listen to a specific route you specify. It would then instantiate both forms and return them to it's view:

```
public function combinedLoginRegisterAction()
{
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'loginForm'    => $this->loginForm,
        'registerForm' => $this->registerForm
    ));
}
```

Obviously you'd need to instantiate the forms beforehand

## Create a ViewHelper that will display each form

The alternative approach would be to create two ViewHelpers that do nothing but to render the Views that are already existant, i.e.:

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'loginForm' => function($vhm) {
            $form      = new LoginForm();
            $renderer  = $vhm->getServiceLocator()->get('viewrenderer');
            $viewModel = new ViewModel(array(
                'form' => $form
            ));
            $viewModel->setTemplate('your\normal\login\template');
            return $renderer->render($viewModel);
        }
    )
)
```

You would then be able to render your form in **any view** like this:

```
echo $this->loginForm();
```

Obviously you'd simply need to repeat the above mentioned step for the registerform.

**important**

Please note that the viewhelper above is not a clean version (and it's probably buggy :D). There's several things to consider when creating this. For your own sake: i would prefer the first solution of having a dedicated Controller that lists both actions and then have it's separate controllers handle the workflow. Once a users submits either form, it doesn't matter if on the next request only one form will be displayed, as that's the action he chose to do anyways.

Comment: If you need to ask: do the first solution and not the 2nd :S you'll only trouble yourself, trust me ;)

Comment: Yes, whenever you send one of the forms, they will find their destination in either LoginController OR RegisterController. So the workflow doesn't leave their designated controllers. That third controller is simply used to instantiate both forms and have them passed to one view.